# Button Click Toggles Div to change and use transition on input width

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a simple button that when pressed, expands an input to the left of it and changes to a form. I would like to use just jQuery and Bootstrap 3 if possible.

It would simply be something like a button that says newsletter:
(mine is pull-right  and orange if it matters)

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> News Letter</a>
```

and when the button is pressed, I would like it to transition to an input field and submit for their email:

```
<form class="form-inline">
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="enter your email">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Submit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
</form>
```

If possible, I would like it to have a .5s transition effect when it does it.

Here is a jsfiddle with the button, and the input+button, side by side.
http://jsfiddle.net/Aa7S9/4/

**EDIT: I put in the jQuery that changes the DOM. I didn't want to have it in there before because I was afraid it might be the entirely wrong approach. It just uses the .ReplaceWith() function so I don't know how I would achieve a transition.**

**EDIT 2: So I am able to have it replace the button element with my form elements, and if I focus on the input box I can get the transition to occur, but for some reason chaining on .focus() after the jquery updates doesn't focus it. Also, I'd like the box to stay the new size once it's expanded if possible, even if they select out of it.**

Comment: I don't think you're gonna get much help unless you actually show some of the Javascript that you tried to write yourself.

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried yourself, so we can help you with it. Stackoverflow is for help programming, not asking others to do it for you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means a JavaScript or JQuery expert, but here's an attempt at an answer since no one else seems to have helped you.

Take a look at the [JQuery Effects page](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) for an idea of some of the nifty things it can do out of the box. [JQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) also has some elements that correspond to common design patterns, which you might think of as jQuery's equivalent (in JavaScript) to what Bootstrap is offering (in CSS).

I updated [your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aa7S9/5/) with a really crappy sliding effect just so you could get the idea. I'm sure once you get the hang of it you can do much better than I did. Here's the breakdown of the JavaScript:

```
/* We make JQuery objects out of the main pieces */
var div_container = $('<div clas="input-group"></div>');
var input_text = $('<input type="text" class="pull-right form-control input-lg" id="transition">');
var button = $('<span class="input-group-btn"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btnwarning">Submit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></button></span>');
/* stick them together */
div_container.append(input_text);
div_container.append(button);
/* and stash them in preparation for the effect */
div_container.hide().insertAfter($(this).parent());
/* animate out the button that was clicked (2000ms=2 seconds of animation)*/
$(this).slideUp(2000);
/* and reveal our new content behind it */
div_container.slideDown(2000);
```